# Excel get cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel

i want to search a list in excell for the word "dog" and it works but if the word is "good dog" it does not detect it.

=LOOKUP(2;1/(C6:AH6="dog");ROW(C:AH))

Comment: If you are looking for a cell that just contains dog without any other words/letters then use `Substitute`. If the length of that formula result is 0 then that cell only contains dog. otherwise it may contain "good dog", "bad dog",  "doggy" or any other *dog* type words.

Comment: Does it work if you try the wildcard using  `="*dog*"`

Comment: no it just takes the asterisks as a word and not a wildcard

Comment: It appears you want to know which column the first cell that includes “Dog” anywhere in its text.  What about simply `MATCH(“*Dog*”,C6:AH6”)`.  This would produce which relative column between C and AH is the first to include an instance of “Dog”.

Comment: This finds the first occurence of the word "dog" but i want to know the last cell that includes "Dog" not the first.

Comment: @cherry84 This is a different requirement than what you provided in your question.  This is easy if you are using Excel O365.  What version of Excel are you on?

Comment: i use excell 2016 version. isn't there any alternative for what i want?

Comment: Anybody can help me??

Answer (score 0):

You can use match entire cell contents when you find it
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it:

```
=XMATCH("*dog*",C6:AH6,2,-1)
```

The third parameter lets you use the wildcard/s and the fourth parameter lets you search last to first so you get the last match first.

It gives you the relative column the last match is found in. So, say, column 9. You'll have to convert if you want the absolute column, or use A6:AH6 for the matching (since it looks to the END first, even if columns A or B have a spurious match, neither would be found unless it did not exist at all in the relevent columns (C-AH) and it would give you the column number directly. If the relative column is all that's needed, no worries.

If using an older version of Excel without `XMATCH`, another way to reverse the order of columns (or rows, as one would need to, say, find the last occurrence of something in a table) is to use `INDEX` and for the columns, use `COLUMNS(C6:AH6)+1-COLUMN(C6:AH6), or if there are only a few columns, type out the array constant for them (so, if six columns, it would be` {6,5,4,3,2,1}` - note the reversal?). Even here, 32 or so numbers to type isn't beastly (well, not too beastly), but it does not allow for more to be inserted or added without retyping it.

And just as easily and directly, the following `XLOOKUP` would do as well:

```
=XLOOKUP("*dog*",C6:AH6,COLUMN(C:AH),,2,-1)
```

for much the same set of reasons. It gives the absolute column number directly, due to the `COLUMN(C:AH)` parameter, but could be changed to `SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNs(C:AH))` to give the relative column number. Other approaches to the relative/absolute column number abound.

(By the way, the use of `TRANSPOSE` lets  right-left become up-down, and the opposite. But using the row/column reversal technique above you can get all four transpositions.)